# Kill Java app process tree run from Bash script with Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a script that runs a java application and keeps running foreground.
What I want to achieve is to close the java application when I issue Ctrl+c.

Suppose something like this:

bash-file-1:

```
trap "stopit; exit" SIGINT
echo "Going to run java app"
source bash-file-2.sh
```

bash-file-2.sh:

```
exec java -jar myapp.jar
```

- The stopit() function just looks for a .pid file an kills the process. It works fine when running the app in background.

What happens here is that, when I issue Ctrl+c, I exit the console mode, but the application keeps running in background. I'm guessing this is because the application is running in another shell because of the 'exec' command. Is this correct?

How can I trap ctrl+c and call the stopit function in this case?

**EDIT**

The java app that I am running is a wrapper jar that calls the actual jar file.

It would be something like this:

```
bash1 -> bash2 -> wrapper.jar -> myapp.jar
```

Comment: `exec` replaces your process with the other, `stopit` would no long exist in that process, but you probably don't really need the `exec` you can just have the `java...` and it will execute that command as though you had typed it

Comment: @EricRenouf I have edited the question, I have tried what you said and realized that the problem comes from a jar invoking another jar. May it be?

Comment: How is the invocation happening, I mean the second jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your child process (Java app) spawns new processes, you'll need to kill the complete process tree rooted at your app.

First, define a (generic) helper [`killtree`](https://github.com/randomir/envie/blob/master/scripts/envie#L160) function:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prints all descendant of a process `ppid`, level-wise, bottom-up.
# Usage: _get_proc_descendants ppid
function _get_proc_descendants() {
    local pid ppid="$1"
    local children=$(ps hopid --ppid "$ppid")
    for pid in $children; do
        echo "$pid"
        _get_proc_descendants "$pid"
    done
}

# Kills all process trees rooted at each of the `pid`s given,
# along with all of their ancestors.
# Usage: killtree [pid1 pid2 ...]
function killtree() {
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        local pids=("$1" $(_get_proc_descendants "$1"))
        kill -TERM "${pids[@]}" &>/dev/null
        shift
    done
}
```

Then, in your `trap`, say:

```
trap "killtree $java_app_pid; exit" SIGINT
```

where the `$java_app_pid` is the PID of your Java app (you said you have in a pid file).

Alternatively, you can define `killtree` to kill only descendants of the PIDs:

```
function killtree() {
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        local pids=($(_get_proc_descendants "$1"))
        kill -TERM "${pids[@]}" &>/dev/null
        shift
    done
}
```

and simplify your `trap` (kill script's children):

```
trap "killtree $$; exit" SIGINT
```